# How do I keep a count that stays on the correct number even after I close the python program

Tags: python, numbers, file-handling, counting

I came up with a solution that I could just have a text file with 0 in it initially and everytime I use the program I take the number in the text file and increase it by 1 and then read the text file to get number in rotation but there seems to be an error.
The code works for the first time, it adds 1 to 0 and makes it 1 but adds some spaces before it for which I used the replace command but still I am facing an error.

My code is as follows:

"def count_incr():

```
f=open("entry count.txt","r+")
v=f.readlines()
for i in v:
    count=int(i)
    count+=1
    count=str(count)
    count.replace(" ","")
    f.truncate(0)
f.write(count)
f.close()
```

count_incr()"

The error is as follows:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Technical Gossip\Desktop\Project\Input and insertion.py", line 27, in 
count_incr()
File "C:\Users\Technical Gossip\Desktop\Project\Input and insertion.py", line 19, in count_incr
count=int(i)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x001'"

Comment: Can you show the code where you write the count to the file? Also if this doesn't work for some odd reason, and though it is overkill a single table single row single column database would work.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII I'm not keen on using this specific method only, so if you have a better one please let me know, and I write count to the file in the second to last line itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`truncate` changes the length of the file but does not rewind it.  When you write the new count, you're still positioned at the end of the old file.  The operating system helpfully pads with zero bytes out to that point.

Instead of `truncate`, use `f.seek(0)`.  You might consider adding a newline, but that's up to you.